# How to check the connection is already opened with isValid(0)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i created a connection object (java.sql.Connection).

can i use this code to check the connection is already opened.

```
if (connection != null  && connection.isValid(0)) {
     return connection;
}
```

and if there is any problem in this please help me.

Answer (score 9):

Be careful with `isValid(0)`, it will test the connection without any timeout, so your application could hang at this point.

It's better to specify a value higher than 0 (in seconds).

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the [isOpen()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/connect/spi/Connection.html#isOpen%28%29) methode Or [isClosed()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isClosed%28%29) in java.​sql.​Connection

EDIT:

The [isValid()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid%28int%29) Checks internally if the connection isnt closed which would be better IMO as it checks if the connection isValid too.

Comment: am using 'java.​sql.​Connection' object and there is no such method ;-)

Comment: There isn't an `isOpen()` in `java.sql.Connection`, as it states in your link this is only for `com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.Connection`

Comment: from JDK comment: "This method generally cannot be called to determine whether a connection to a database is valid or invalid", so you have to call #isValid(1)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. It's safer than using `isClose()` method, because is also test if the connection is still valid.

Comment: so using (connection != null && !connection.isClose() && connection.isValid(0)) is safe rit?

Comment: there's no need to use `isClose` if you're using `isValid`. `isValid` returns false if the connection is closed.